# Internet stops working randomly

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, file-sharing

My Internet stops working, and it works again when I disconnect a specific computer from the router (ASUS RT-N66U). What could be the problem?

The computer is connected via Ethernet and running Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That computer could have an IP address that conflicts with the router's addressing, or a virus, or something that opens a very large number of TCP/UPD connections towards the internet.

Check it for viruses and if you have any peer-to-peer programs, close them. Make sure that the IP address of the computer is obtained correctly by router's DHCP.